# how can i use TotalRow to show summary in Janus gridex?

Tags: c#, janus

I have a ultragrid in janus with this code

```
        UltraGridColumn col = new UltraGridColumn();
        ultraGrid1.TotalRow = Janus.Windows.GridEX.InheritableBoolean.True;
        col.Caption = "column1";
        col.DataMember = ISOCntrTable.IsoCode.ColumnName;
        col.Key = "column1";
        col.AggregateFunction = Janus.Windows.GridEX.AggregateFunction.Sum;
        col.FormatString = "c";
        col.TotalFormatMode = Janus.Windows.GridEX.FormatMode.UseStringFormat;
        col.TotalFormatString = "SUM={0:c}";
        ultraGrid1.Columns.Add(col);
```

but, no any things show in TotalRow!
how can i show summary in this row?
please help me!

Comment: UltraGridColumn is a class from Infragistics UltrawinGrid. Not sure what has it in common with Janus. Care to explain?

Comment: no problem! please help me about 'AggregateFunction.sum' and 'TotalRoW'.

Comment: Total Row in Janus is a row that is displayed at the bottom, but what you are describing is adding one more column with the "Total" caption, so your question is not clear, please elaborate.

Comment: i'm trying to use TotalRow in the bottom of 'columns1' to show summary of this row! but i don't how?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this code after when you add your column to grid :

```
grd.TotalRow = Janus.Windows.GridEX.InheritableBoolean.True;
grd.RootTable.Columns[10].AggregateFunction = Janus.Windows.GridEX.AggregateFunction.Sum;
```